# How to set serial port NMEA source to QtPositioning in PySide6

Tags: python, pyqt, gps, pyside, nmea

I have a GPS device running on COM7. and I can read NMEA data from serial port.
It seems that QtPositioning support NMEA source . but I can't find any document about setting NMEA source to it.

I wrote some code to trying my best:

```
import PySide6.QtPositioning
import PySide6.QtCore
import PySide6.QtSerialPort

print('createSource')
obj = PySide6.QtCore.QObject()

source = PySide6.QtPositioning.QGeoPositionInfoSource.createDefaultSource(obj)
print(source.availableSources())

print('try Nmea Source')
qpNmea = PySide6.QtPositioning.QNmeaPositionInfoSource( PySide6.QtPositioning.QNmeaPositionInfoSource.RealTimeMode)

print(qpNmea.availableSources())

print('try Serial Port')
# new com9 QIODevice
com7 = PySide6.QtSerialPort.QSerialPort("com7" )
com7.setBaudRate(PySide6.QtSerialPort.QSerialPort.Baud9600)
com7.setDataBits(PySide6.QtSerialPort.QSerialPort.Data8)
com7.setParity(PySide6.QtSerialPort.QSerialPort.NoParity)
com7.setStopBits(PySide6.QtSerialPort.QSerialPort.OneStop)
com7.setFlowControl(PySide6.QtSerialPort.QSerialPort.NoFlowControl)
com7.open(PySide6.QtSerialPort.QSerialPort.ReadWrite)

com7.open(PySide6.QtSerialPort.QSerialPort.ReadOnly)

print(com7.readLine())

print('setDevice')
qpNmea.setDevice(com7)
qpNmea.startUpdates()
print(qpNmea.device())

print('others')

print(PySide6.QtPositioning.QGeoSatelliteInfoSource.availableSources())
print(PySide6.QtPositioning.QGeoPositionInfoSource.availableSources())
print(PySide6.QtPositioning.QNmeaPositionInfoSource.availableSources())

print ('end')
```

OUTPUT:

```
createSource
['winrt', 'nmea']
try Nmea Source
['winrt', 'nmea']
try Serial Port
b''
setDevice
<PySide6.QtSerialPort.QSerialPort(0x28928ad9680) at 0x000002892956F800>
others
[]
['winrt', 'nmea']
['winrt', 'nmea']
end
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Qt6 Docs: [NMEA Data](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/location-positioning-cpp.html#nmea-data).

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks for providing the link. But I still did not find how to set serial port.

Comment: Well, I obviously cannot test your example, so you should edit your question and show the output. Which specific parts aren't working? You should always avoid using `SIGNAL/SLOT` to make connections as it is very error-prone. Do this instead: `qpNmea.positionUpdated.connect(slot)`, where `slot` is a python function that receives a `QGeoPositionInfo` object. You should probably also make this connection as well: `qpNmea.errorOccurred.connect(slot)`.

Comment: The current output in your question isn't much help, because you haven't connected any signals to anything. These APIs aren't synchronous. You need to create an application object, run an event-loop and wait for responses via signal handlers.